# Moving data between interfaces without violating SOLID principles?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, solid-principles

**TL;DR:** What's the best way to move data between interfaces without violating SOLID principles?

---

I might be over-thinking this and I don't intend to be dogmatic in regard to SOLID principles; but I wanted to get some input. I've been refactoring a shopping cart to be more "SOLID" and there's a method that I wrote that seems like "code smell" to me (maybe it isn't).

I have a `CartHelper` class that looks something like this (I've simplified it a bit for brevity):

```
public class CartHelper
{
    IEnumerable Products;
    IEnumerable Subscriptions;

    // ...Other Class Methods...

    [HttpPost]
    public void AddItem(int productVariantID)
    {
        var product = ProductService.GetByVariantID(productVariantID);

        if (product != null)
        {
            if (product.Type == (int)Constants.ProductTypes.Subscription)
                Subscriptions = Subscriptions.Concat(new [] { product });

            Products = Products.Concat(new [] { product });
            CartService.AddItem(productVariantID);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void RemoveItem(int productVariantID)
    {
        Subscriptions = Subscriptions.Where(s => s.VariantID != productVariantID);
        Products = Products.Where(p => p.VariantID != productVariantID);

        CartService.RemoveItem(productVariantID);
    }

    public decimal GetCartTotalBeforeDiscount()
    {
        return Products.Sum(p => p.Price);
    }

    public IEnumerable GetCartItems()
    {
        var products = (from p in Products
                        select new CartSummaryItem
                        {
                           ProductID = p.ProductID,
                           Title = p.Title,
                           Description = p.Description,
                           Price = p.Price,
                           // ...Assign other applicable properties here...
                        } 
                        as ICartSummaryItem);

        return products;
    }

    // ...Other Class Methods...
}
```

The part that seems like "code-smell" to me (and there might be more that's bad here) is the `GetCartItems()` method. Something about it seems funky to me, but I can't think of an alternative that is any better.

I'm converting to `ICartItem` because there are some properties added that need to be passed to the view but they don't make sense on an `IStoreProduct` or an `IStoreSubscription` (Interface Segregation Principle).

I've thought about adding `ConvertProductToCartItem()` and `ConvertSubscriptionToCartItem()` methods to the `CartHelper`, but that seems like a violation of Single Responsibility Principle. Would it make sense to have a CartItemFactory that accepts `IStoreProduct`s and `IStoreSubscription`s and for conversion? That seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead for such a simple conversion.

One of the solutions that I came up with is to define an explicit cast method:

```
public class StoreProduct : IStoreProduct
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    // ...Properties...

    public ICartItem ToCartItem()
    {
        // Will call explicit cast implementation
        return (CartItem) this;
    }

    // Explicit cast conversion for Product as CartItem
    public static explicit operator CartItem(StoreProduct product)
    {
        return new CartItem()
        {
            Price = product.Price,
            Discount = product.Price,
            SalePrice = Helper.CalculateSalePriceForProduct(product),
            // ...Assign other applicable properties here...
        };
    }
}
```

Which let's me change my `GetCartItems` method to this much cleaner implementation:

```
public IEnumerable GetCartItems()
{
    return Products.Select(p => p.ToCartSummaryItem());
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that this also violates Single Responsibility Principle by coupling `ICartItem` and `CartItem` to the `StoreProduct` Class. I also considered an extension method instead of the cast conversion, but that's not any better or different.

Should I just make my concrete `StoreProduct` class implement the `ICartItem` interface and put the cart-specific properties there? Maybe I should just rewrite the `CartHelper` so that it only has ICartItems (i.e., remove the `IProduct`s)? Both of those options seem like violations of the Single Responsibility Principle. Maybe the solution will become obvious after I get some sleep...

**So, I guess what my question boils down to is: what's the best way to move data between interfaces without violating SOLID principles?**

Any suggestions? Maybe I should just move on and not worry about it (i.e., don't be dogmatic about SOLID)? Have I answered my own question? Maybe this belongs in programmers.stackexchange, I hope this isn't too subjective.

---

Also, in case it's helpful, this is what my interfaces look like:

```
public interface IProductBase
{
    int ProductID { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    // ... Other Properties...
}


public interface IStoreProduct : IProductBase
{
    int VariantID { get; set; }
    decimal Discount { get; set; }
    // ... Other Properties...

    ICartItem ToCartItem();
}


public interface ISubscription : IProductBase
{
    SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }
    // ... Other Properties...

    ICartItem ToCartItem();
}


public interface ICartItem : IProductBase
{
    decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
    // ... Other Properties...
}
```

**Update:** Added post attributes for clarity.

Comment: I see your point of not wanting the StoreProduct to take the dependenct of the ICartItem, but seeing as ICartItem is just a more specialized "view" of the StoreProduct you could just pass it into the constructor of the CartItem (or use a factory if you dont want the hit in CartItem either).

Comment: I personally think that the Law of Demeter is obsolete in times of shiny objects, interfaces and unit testing so id just make CartItem contain a StoreProduct (ICartItem.IStoreProduct) and just add the added needed functionality, but that could lead to rage depending on yoru collegues.

Comment: @MrDosu Since, CartItem is a specialized view of StoreProduct, I think the Law of Demeter isn't broken here. I could pass StoreProduct into a CartItem's constructor, but that's ultimately no better than my ToCartItem() method. I also need to handle ISubscription instances too, so I would need to add an additional constructor for that case.

Comment: @MrDosu but what about a cart item that is not a product; a service perhaps?

Comment: @Andy Imo then its either that carts are always the same representing different objects (those objects would be something generic like ICartable) or CartItems have specific behaviour depending on what they make available then you have ProductCartItem and ServiceCartItem both implementing ICartItem (and possibly having a parent CartItemBase)

Comment: @MrDosu Agreed; that's why I think he should go with such an approach even if he only currently has products.  That would be in line with the Open / Closed principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to your suggestions (Fendy, Andy, MrDosu), here's the far-cleaner Facade implementation:

```
public class Cart
{
    private List<ICartItem> CartItems;

    // ...Other Class Methods...

    [HttpPost]
    public void AddItem(int productVariantID)
    {
        var product = ProductService.GetByVariantID(productVariantID);

        if (product != null)
        {
            CartItems.Add(CartItemConverter.Convert(product));
            CartService.AddItem(productVariantID);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void RemoveItem(int productVariantID)
    {
        CartItems.RemoveAll(c => c.VariantID == productVariantID);
        CartService.RemoveItem(productVariantID);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ICartItem> GetCartItems()
    {
        return CartItems;
    }

    // ...Other Class Methods...
}
```

Since I only care about cart-related properties after my items have been added to the cart, I can remove references to IStoreProduct and ISubscription. If I ever end up needing to extract more information (YAGNI applies here), I can use the Adapter pattern (via the ProductService) to populate the necessary data.

Answer (score 1):

My simple answer is that a StoreProduct is not a cart item.  You could have a ProductCartItem which implements ICartItem.  This implementation would contain a reference to IStoreProduct.  Your cart item has things a product doesn't, like quantity, discount price, current price, etc.

In this way you're not violating SRP or other SOLID principles.  Your cart item might record the price at the time the product was added to the cart, even if the price for in shelf items changes.  The cart item could also use the StoreProduct for its upc, without you needing to store it in the cart item itself.

I think this is the direction you should head in as the design will allow you to add cart items which are not products (say ServiceCartItem).

Finally, you may need some other types, perhaps a ProductCartItem factory that constructs a new cart item from the product.  It depends on how much logic is involved in adding something to a cart.

Answer (score 1):

### What is SRP?

I want to emphasize that SRP, S from SOLID is Single Responsibility Principle. Means that a class / object only has 1 responsibility and no more. If the class is changed, then there is for 1 and only 1 reason, no more.

### IEnumerable?

Second, why do you use `IEnumerable` (instead of `List`) and using `Concat`? I can't find the pros of using `IEnumerable` and `Concat` over `List`.

### Now let's look at the implementation of your `CartHelper`.

First from the naming, it is `Helper`. What is it / what is the helper? What is the responsibility?

**AddItem**

Moving to `AddItem`, I can see that the logic is:

1. using the product id provided, get the product using service.
2. If the product exists and product type is `Subscription`, add into `Subscription`.
3. Last, add into `Product` list and `CartService`.

In my point of view, the method is doing too much. I think it will better if you shift point 1 somewhere else, or even the client will be ok. It will make the AddItem to only accept `IProductBase` and add into `Product` list. What about `Subscription` list? Scrap that, you don't need it. Using LINQ `where`, you can find subset of subscriptions from `Product` list using its type property.

From client point of view, what can this method provide to user when a specified product is not found during `AddItem`? You don't `throw` any exceptions or anything. Client will just add the `product` and the they will not know whether the product has been added or not. They will just expect that everything has been done and no error handling there.

I don't understand what is `CartService` doing. However I think it will be fine if you want to implement like that.

**RemoveItem**

Same as `AddItem`, you can scrap the `Subscription` list. Regarding passing the product id or `IProductBase` class, it is comparable each other.

**GetCartTotalBeforeDiscount**

Wait, this class can add item, remove item, and now get the total? Following SRP, if you want to change the logic for getting total before discount, you need to modify this class. Now it has 2 reasons for changing the class, 1st is if you want to change how it manage item collection (add/remove/get) and 2nd how to calculate the total before discount. Shift this responsibility into other class. If you think it is convertible to add the method in `CartHelper`, use a facade pattern.

**GetCartItems**

Now you want to get the cart items. But wait, you converted it into a specific class instead of just returning it? What is the use of `IProductBase` interface when you just converting each product into specific class? Moreover, now it has 3 reasons for changing the class, now with conversion as a reason.

So how do you want to improve this GetCartItems? Change into `GetProducts` and return the `IEnumerable` of `IProductBase` and everything is done in the class. Then create some `interfaces` for product conversion such as:

```
class CartItemConverter : IProductConverter<ICartItem>{
    public IEnumerable<ICartItem> GetConverted(IEnumerable<IProductBase> products){
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Now you has the freedom for conversion.

Note: There maybe other better pattern such as `Decorator` for this case. but IMHO this one is the simplest one and having the most similar structure with your code.

Comment: Good points all around. I agree that "Helper" isn't descriptive, but I wasn't sure what else to call it and it seemed to be a common naming convention. You're right about dropping the Subscription IEnumerable, it exists because there's code that uses this class that depends on it. But, since I'm refactoring it anyway, there's no reason not to change it. The CartService adds the cart items to the DB; the cart needs to be accessible from multiple domains. There's more to code than I've shown, and it handles errors; I removed some things for brevity, but thanks for mentioning it.